# Double request submission in IE7

Tags: facebook, form-submit

Any body have any experience (or even better a solution) to IE7 submitting a request to a webserver twice?

Its seems that any POST or GETs I send are being called twice. This only happens in IE7. Chrome, FF, Safari and IE8 are fine.

I'm running IE7 "through" IE8 using Browser Mode in developer tools - could this be the cause?

Comment: please, show sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got to the bottom of this - the problem was the javascript added to make Facebooks server fbml work.

The offending piece of code was this:

```
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

This code was used in a tile which made it common to all pages. Moving it to a single page where its used (invite friends to application) cleared the issue right up.

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the JavaScript `.submit()` in addition to your `<input type="submit">` ?